# Changing the information before serialization

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

I have a database model like:-

```
class Script(db.Model):
   path = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

and a serializer like:-

```
class ScriptSchema(ma.Schema):
   class Meta:
      fields = (
          'path'
   )
```

My question is that when I dump the data after querying:-

```
all_scripts_orm = Script.query.all()
all_scripts = ScriptSchema(many=True).dump(all_scripts_orm)
```

I get data in the form of

```
[
   {"path": "Sample_folder/Sample_Script_1.txt"},
   {"path": "Sample_folder/Sample_script_2.txt"}
]
```

But I want to be able to do extract only the name of the script and serialize it

```
[
    {"path": "Sample_script_1.txt"},
    ...
]
```

How do I approach this problem as I don't want to make another column just for name in the Script Model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Function` field, documentation example [here](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_fields.html#function-fields) and documented [here](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.fields.html#marshmallow.fields.Function). For example:

```
from os import path as op

class ScriptSchema(ma.Schema):
   class Meta:
      fields = (
          'path'
   )

   path = fields.Function(lambda obj: op.basename(obj.path))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pjcunningham.